# how to add a relationship between tables in the dataset

Tags: asp.net, dataset, resultset, datarelation

I have the following code to get the get the relationship between the tables in the same dataset , but when run the following code i encounter with error saying , these columns currently dont have unique values

```
       DataResultSetDataSet dataset = resultSet as DataResultSetDataSet;
        System.Data.DataSet menuDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        menuDataSet = dataset.Set;
        menuDataSet.DataSetName = "Menus";
        menuDataSet.Tables[0].TableName = "Menu";
        DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("ParentChild", menuDataSet.Tables["Menu"].Columns["MenuID"], menuDataSet.Tables["Menu"].Columns["ParentID"], true);
        relation.Nested = true;
        menuDataSet.Relations.Add(relation);

        menuXml= menuDataSet.GetXml();
        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to join the table to itself?

Comment: ya i am establishing parent child relationship , based on the items contained in the dataset

Comment: I mean it looks like you're joining table `Menu` to table `Menu`.  Is that a typo, or is that what you really intended to do?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , the problem i was facing was my datset contained duplicate values now i got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code isn't a typo (i.e., you're **not** trying to relate the table Menu to itself), check the values in the two columns (MenuID and ParentID).  Without knowing exactly how your table(s) are set up, I would suspect that ParentID has repeated values, which is why you're getting the error you are.