# Create DataRelation with different columns name in both tables

Tags: c#, dataset, datarelation

when creating DataRelation between two tables in the same dataset should the names of columns in both tables be identical ??

Comment: Yes but it does not have to be.

Look at this [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005672/how-to-add-a-relationship-between-tables-in-the-dataset?rq=1

Comment: But after i do this i got null calling DataRow.getParentRow(relationName)